# How to make the div responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, styles

i was working on this [site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/salisburylandscaping/) in wordpress using cutomizeit theme.everything was responsive untill i custom added this into my homepage

```
<div class="hilight-hometext">
<div id="hilightbox">
<div class="hilightbox-text">
<h2>At Salisbury we want everyone to understand their landscaping choices</h2>
<p>Our latest landscaping innovation is our Outdoor Vision questionnaire. We’ll guide you through a set of questions that will help you realize what you want out of your yard.    </p>

</div>
<!-- end tier 2 text -->
<div class="hilightbox-action">

<a class="myButton" href="resources/the-outdoor-vision-tool/">GET STARTED</a>

<p>Your Outdoor Vision</p>

</div>
<!-- end tier 2 action -->
</div></div>
```

this div is not responsive.how can i  make it responsive so that everything goes fine . Please Help!! Thanks!!

Comment: which theme u are using in this site

Comment: oo thats bad look but side design is good

Comment: no i mean theme looks ugly but your site design  is awesome i still ur texture background for my website. eeeeeee

Comment: you can go here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54485/responsive-tempalates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011812/style-not-displaying-when-called-using-page-id-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Add in CSS max-width/min-width & max-height/min-height!

Comment: cud u please explain me how exactly to do it

Comment: #hilightbox{background: url(../img/action-bg.jpg) !important;
width: 100%  !important;
min-width: 900px;
margin: 20px auto  !important;
overflow: hidden;}

Answer (score 0):

change   the `span4 fp-two` class css `@media` and change the image width according to the media.

```
.span4.fp-two{
  float : left;
}
```

Comment: sorry i didn get you.can u explain please!!

Comment: change the float css of .sapn.fp-two class. By default float:none apply for this class. and the center div Image width is too long soit push the third div to bottom. change the image with using '%' not 'px'

Comment: shud i add this to my css file? .span4.fp-two{
  float : left;
}

Comment: first check it through Inspect Element and if you are ok with it add to your @media  css file

Comment: i have no clue on how to make it work..i am a newbie in web development

Comment: use chrome for best understanding. see this https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements.

Comment: it wud b good if u explain me where exactly i shud place the code and change the width

Comment: Just now I sea your website. I thin you have changes the responsive design of your website right???. Now it's looking good. for this design no need to write above code.

Comment: but the get started button nd the logo is breaking in responsive

Comment: set the background-position: center; for logo image and reduce the padding for getting started button.