# Style not displaying when called using page-id in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I was working in this site [My Site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/gracefamily/) . In the home page I have called the contents of a page using the following code

```
<?php 
$id=48; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;  
?>
```

And my content is

```
<strong>Atlanta Weekly Schedule:</strong>

Sunday Explosive Service 10am - 12:15pm

Wednesday Bible Study, 7 - 8:30pm

Friday Freedom Night (Prayer, Prophetic, Miracle &amp; Deliverance Service), 7 - 10pm

&nbsp;

&nbsp;

<strong>New York Weekly Schedule:</strong>

Sunday Explosive Service 10am - 12:15pm

Wednesday Bible Study, 7 - 8:30pm

Friday Freedom Night (Prayer, Prophetic, Miracle &amp; Deliverance Service), 7 - 10pm
```

As you can see the I have given two heading with  tag .But when it is displayin in the home page the source shows th ecode with  but not displaying as bold.Someone please help me!! THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following CSS to your code

strong { font-weight: bold; }

It will work

Answer (score 1):

I have reviewed your website as mentioned and traced your css file. In reset.css you have mentioned font-weight: inherit for strong tag.

So its trying to inherits this property from its parent element.

For more information visit: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp

Comment: whats the solution then?

Comment: You can write css like this:
p strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}